# Set Auto pay for online payments on repeating invoices

Tags: xero-api

When creating a repeating invoice via the API and setting "Approve for Sending" is it possible to send in a flag to also set "Offer Auto Pay" (stripe in our case) or at least have it turned on in the payment settings section?

[image]

**Update**
Currently as of time of posting it is not possible. I have created a User Voice here so if anyone is interested in this please add some votes. Thanks https://xero.uservoice.com/forums/5528-accounting-api/suggestions/46766098-set-offer-auto-pay-via-the-api